# iOS: Save which is the preferred EKCalendar some how?

Tags: ios, calendar, eventkit

I'm building a small calendar application where a user can select which calendar the events should be entered into. So the users picks their calendar of choice from a pickerview in the settingsmodal, then when they enter a new event I should be able to get that calendar object to create the event some how. I tried writing the object to a plist, by putting it in a NSDictionary but I don't think its able to store objects of that type. Can I save the name and calendartype of the calendar and somehow get the EKCalendar-object with those two paramaters? Preferably without having to manually loop through them all.

Also, how do I programmatically create new calendarevents? I have the following information about each event; start-time is Now, end-time in a minute-value from the startingpoint, if its a full day, the calendar (if I can get the top bit to work) and the event name.

Thanks in advance, 
Christopher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you read the [EventKit Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009765) first. It explains how to create and save new events.

If you want to save information about the selected calendar and retrieve the calendar later from that information, you can use the `calendarIdentifier` property of `EKCalendar` in conjunction with the `-calendarWithIdentifier:` method of `EKEventStore`:

```
// Save the identifier
NSString *identifier = [aCalendar calendarIdentifier];
...

// Retrieve the calendar later
NSString *identifier = ...;
EKCalendar *aCalendar = [eventStore calendarWithIdentifier:identifier];
```

[EKCalendar Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Reference/EKCalendarClassRef/Reference/Reference.html)
[EKEventStore Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKEventStoreClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/EKEventStore)